# How I could read this data with simple Ajax/Jquery format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to read for example the value of "ToUSD" of "CoinBase" of this json data:

```
{"Success":true,"Message":"990 api calls remaining.","Data":{"CoinName":"Bitcoin","CoinTag":"BTC","BlockCount":470624,"Difficulty":678760110082.99000000,"BlockReward":12.5,"IsBlockExplorerOnline":true,"IsExchangeOnline":true,"Algorithm":"SHA-256","ExchangeRates":[{"Exchange":"Bitstamp","ToUSD":2820.0100,"ToBTC":1.00000000,"Volume":7366.04190649,"TimeStamp":1497054312.993},{"Exchange":"Coinbase","ToUSD":2837.2700,"ToBTC":1.00000000,"Volume":0.00000000,"TimeStamp":1497054312.773},{"Exchange":"BTCe","ToUSD":2757.9990,"ToBTC":1.00000000,"Volume":4082.27473000,"TimeStamp":1497054300.263},{"Exchange":"Bitfinex","ToUSD":2803.4000,"ToBTC":1.00000000,"Volume":8909.31556495,"TimeStamp":1497054101.677},{"Exchange":"itBit","ToUSD":2815.9800,"ToBTC":1.00000000,"Volume":942.32890000,"TimeStamp":1497054073.267}],"BlockTimeInSeconds":600,"HealthStatus":"Healthy","Message":""}}
```

And I would like to have the simple format:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
 dataType: "json",
 url: ...
```

Anyone can help me?  I have already tried but the console displays this error:

> (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I think I'm not reading the data well. Thanks so much.

Comment: the issue is you are trying to get a resource from a server that does not allow you to "borrow" it's resources in a browser - that's what CORS is all about, protecting ones resources - i.e there's nothing you can do about it, the server would need to allow you access

Comment: If you have no control of the server, there is nothing you can do about that. Btw https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/merchants/technical-faq#ajax

Comment: reading the above link, your only option is to make the request from **your** server

Comment: So why they give people keys for the API? The page is CoinWarz :'(

Comment: You still can work with the API on the server side, but just not on client side.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

The website does not send a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` which means access for data is denied, and you wil have to find another way/request another page that has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

> Lines 13 - 22 show the HTTP response from the server on domain
>   http://bar.other. In response, the server sends back an
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, shown above in line 16. The use of
>   the Origin header and of Access-Control-Allow-Origin show the access
>   control protocol in its simplest use. In this case, the server
>   responds with a Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * which means that the
>   resource can be accessed by any domain in a cross-site manner. If the
>   resource owners at http://bar.other wished to restrict access to the
>   resource to be only from http://foo.example, they would send back:
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
>
> Note that now, no domain other than http://foo.example (identified by
>   the ORIGIN: header in the request, as in line 10 above) can access the
>   resource  in a cross-site manner.  The Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>   header should contain the value that was sent in the request's Origin
>   header.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to `.htaccess` file to access the other website data.

`<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>`

Or

For Php Code - add at the top of the page

`header("access-control-allow-origin: *");`